# Copying Gif with UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipasteboard

I want to copy .gif images to clipboard, so as user can paste that gif images from application to mails, etc...

I have tried :

```
@import MobileCoreServices;

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs37/f/2008/283/a/b/KaleidoCoils_animated__gif_by_1389AD.gif"]];
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeGIF];
```

What happens is the gif is "copied" but my device is no longer to paste.  This might be the right code, but there might be a setting on the storyboard that I have to change in order to allow the usage of gifs and `UIPasteboard`.

Application https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/animated-3d-emoji+emoticons/id429348043?mt=8 already does this.

Please help me.

Comment: I added this code into the app delegate of an app that I am working on to test - it successfully copied a GIF to my iPad's clipboard and I was able to paste it into a message. Could there be something else you're missing?

Comment: Hmm... I am implementing this into a custom keyboard which requires me to have two storyboards, one for the actual app (showing how to set up the keyboard) and one for the actual keyboard itself.  Is there some sort of permission I need to give in order to use gifs or something?

Comment: Actually you know, I think you're right - here's my keyboard's properties: http://i.imgur.com/jjPw2XH.png - do you have "RequestsOpenAccess" ?

Comment: yes, I do have those same exact setting I'm trying again, but I don't believe that it is working have you been able to get it to work? By the way, I appreciate you helping me so much

Comment: No worries :) - can't think of any other changes - did you enable full access for the install keyboard in Settings > General > Keyboards > Your Keyboard > Allow Full Access?

Comment: Yes I did, I still am having no luck :(

Comment: Aright so basically now I believe that it is copying the gif from my project, but it doens't let me paste it.  Is this from the gif not being in correct format/size?

Comment: We had some issues with sending gifs in messages because of their size, but I reckon pasting should still work. Maybe try different apps (email, notes, messages) - you're on a real device right?

Comment: Yes, I am on a real device and i'm trying to copy in iMessage which is what my app needs to do since it is in a keyboard, I am able to get the code to work on my main storyboard, but not on my other storyboard I am using for my keyboard

Comment: are there any things I can change in my settings of my storyboard to allow it work with gifs/UIPasteboard?

Comment: Alright - no changes I can remember (the copying code can go anywhere, not just in a view controller) : are you able to extract the relevant code to a new project to test and share?

Comment: Wait, you can't use this on a view controller are you sure because my mainstoryboard is a viewcontroller and it works and same with my keyboard

Comment: What I meant to say is the UIPasteboard code can be run from any class so I don't see how it would have something to do with the UIViewController

Comment: That is what I though, but the code only works on my mainstoryboard viewController, but when I bring it to my viewController on my keyboard view controller I am unable to paste at all when "copying" the gif.

Comment: Ok, but I think you'll find that you can put that code anywhere in your main project but as soon as you try to run it from within the keyboard extension that's when the issue occurs. At this stage the only way I can help is if I see a sample project with the same issue

Comment: Alright is there any possible way for me to share my project with you?